# Cant use Loginctl in python script ran by system service

Tags: python, script, arch-linux, services, manjaro

Im trying to have a systemd service that runs a beacon scanner script in python, this script lock or unlocks my computer when rssi from my clock is lower/higher.

Script works when ran from terminal, but fails to run Loginctl lock/unlock-sessions when ran as a service.

`Jun 12 13:22:28 manjaroOSs python[22082]: -55 Jun 12 13:22:28 manjaroOSs python[22214]: Could not connect to D-Bus server: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Using X1> Jun 12 13:22:28 manjaroOSs python[22082]: -51 Jun 12 13:22:28 manjaroOSs python[22225]: Could not connect to D-Bus server: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Using X1> Jun 12 13:22:28 manjaroOSs python[22082]: -54 Jun 12 13:22:28 manjaroOSs python[22229]: Could not connect to D-Bus server: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Using X1> Jun 12 13:22:28 manjaroOSs loginctl[22231]: Failed to issue method call: Unknown object '/org/freedesktop/login1/session/auto'. Jun 12 13:22:28 manjaroOSs loginctl[22232]: Failed to issue method call: Unknown object '/org/freedesktop/login1/session/auto'. Jun 12 13:22:29 manjaroOSs python[22082]: Scanning... Jun 12 13:22:29 manjaroOSs python[22082]: -54 Jun 12 13:22:29 manjaroOSs python[22234]: Could not connect to D-Bus server: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Using X1> Jun 12 13:22:29 manjaroOSs python[22082]: -52 Jun 12 13:22:29 manjaroOSs python[22239]: Could not connect to D-Bus server: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Using X1>`

Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Clock beacon scanner
Requires=graphical.target
After=graphical.target

[Service]
User=daniel
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/daniel/Documents/github/bluetooth-proximity/examples/bluetooth_scanner.py 
Type=forking
RestartSec=2
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitInterval=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Snip from python script:

```
LOCK_SCREEN_COMMAND = ["loginctl", "lock-session"]
UNLOCK_SCREEN_COMMAND = ["loginctl", "unlock-session"]

def lock_system():
    global LOCK_COUNT
    if not is_screen_locked() and LOCK_COUNT == 7:
        subprocess.run(LOCK_SCREEN_COMMAND)
        print("Locking")


def unlock_system():
    global UNLOCK_COUNT
    if is_screen_locked() and UNLOCK_COUNT == 10:
        subprocess.run(UNLOCK_SCREEN_COMMAND)
        print("Unlocking")
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.